# XML entity from other file if one file doesn't exist

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

we have the following, but sometime the file doesn't exist

```
    <!ENTITY my SYSTEM "/etc/forms/X-SE.xml">
```

and if the file /etc/forms/X-SE.xml doesn't exist we would like to do the following:

```
    <!ENTITY my SYSTEM "X-SE.xml">
```

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no provision at the XML level for specifying a fallback system entity for a missing system entity.

Instead, you might intervene at the parser level by writing a custom entity resolver or at the HTTP protocol level via code to conditionally redirect.

Comment: Thanks, worked with writing a custom EntityResolver :)